# Uploading attachments to Bugzilla using the Web Services API and Perl

Tags: perl, xml-rpc, bugzilla

I'm experimenting with the Bugzilla Webservices API for uploading attachments to bugs automatically but the base64 encoded messages I'm uploading always end up corrupted when I download them from Bugzilla.

The API doc at http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.0/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/Bug.html#add_attachment specifies that the attachment needs to be base64 encoded, so I'm using a straightforward piece of code to read a local png file, convert to base64 using [MIME::Base64](http://perldoc.perl.org/MIME/Base64.html) and uploading using a Bugzilla Perl client API called [BZ::Client](http://search.cpan.org/dist/BZ-Client/).

The relevant code looks like this -

```
my $client = BZ::Client->new("url" => $url,
                             "user" => $user,
                             "password" => $password);

            open (FILE, "$file") or die "$!";
            binmode FILE;
            read (FILE, $data, -s FILE);
            $base64_encoded_file = encode_base64($data);

            my %params = (
                ids => [ 1 ],
                data => $base64_encoded_file,
                file_name => 'filename.png',
                content_type => "image/png",
                summary => 'blah blah' );


            my $response = '';

            eval {
                $response = $client->api_call("Bug.add_attachment", \%params); # Needs to be hash ref
            } or do {
                print "ERROR: $@\n";        
            };
```

So fairly straightforward.  I believe on the backend the Web Service API uses decode_base64 so I'm surprised this doesn't work.  Even a direct test of the XMLRPC API with the generated base64 string from the Perl still results in a corrupt file.

I have also tried stripping line breaks to no avail as suggested in the [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=412074) about the implementation of the Bug.add_attachment API call.

Anyone had any experience of this before?

Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar problem when trying to do the same with PHP ... I want to add an `application/gzip` attachment and it somehow gets scrambled ... but also trying to send a `plain/text` has the same problem.

Comment: @Robert Conn: Have you manage to solve this issue of "add_attachment" method ?

Comment: @Robert Conn: Have you found solution? can you share ?

I am using a python module for interacting with Bugzilla over XMLRPC
https://git.fedorahosted.org/git/python-bugzilla.git
My Bugzilla version is 4.2.3

By using add_attachment method I can upload files of different extensions (.zip, .jpg etc) , but uploaded files got corrupted. So, I am not sure if this Bugzilla Attachment API is stable or not..

Answer (score 1):

```
read (FILE, $data, -s FILE);
```

This is just wrong: Quote from `perldoc -f read`

```
Attempts to read LENGTH characters of data.
```

The key word is *Attempts*: `read()` is free to read LESS than LENGTH bytes.

If you just want to slurp the contents of FILE you could use:

```
$data = join("", <FILE>);
```