# How to attach file via "Bugzilla XMLRPC access module"

Tags: python, xml-rpc, bugzilla

I am working on bugzilla xml-rpc by using "[Bugzilla XMLRPC access module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-bugzilla)" developed in python.

How I can attach/download bugzilla file by using this module ?

According to [guideline of API](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.2/en/html/api/Bugzilla/Attachment.html) get_attachments_by_bug($bug_id) retrieves and returns the attachments.

But this function didn't worked for me, I got following error message.

```
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'Bugzilla4' object has no attribute 'get_attachments_by_bug'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI:
I am in contact with supplier of python-bugzilla tool and here I got response from them.

"Not all bugzilla XMLRPC APIs are wrapped by python-bugzilla, that's one of them.

The 'bugzilla' command line tool that python-bugzilla ships has commands for
attaching files and downloading attachments, take a look at the code there for
guidance."

---

I've figured out the way how to download/upload attachment by using "Bugzilla XMLRPC access module"

you need to pass the id of attached file as parameter to the following function

**Download:**

```
downloaded_file = bz.download_attachment(attachment_id)
file_name = str(downloaded_file.name)
```

**Upload:**

```
kwards = {
    'contenttype':'application/octet-stream',
   # 'filename': file_path     #there could be more parameters if needed
} 

#attachfile method will return the id of attached file 
bz.attachfile(bug_id, file_path, file_name, **kwards)
```

However attached file got corrupted due to some xmp-rpc API's internal methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516982/add-an-attachment-to-bugzilla-using-xml-rpc-in-vba), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566451/attachments-are-stored-in-base64-format-in-bugzilla-when-uploading-using-xml-rpc) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131197/uploading-attachments-to-bugzilla-using-the-web-services-api-and-perl), that's another issue :)